# Validate file extensions and file size on Drupal 7 file field using the form API

Tags: forms, validation, drupal, drupal-7

I am using Drupal 7 and have a custom module that creates a form that has a file upload field:

```
$form['resume_file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Resume Upload'),      
);
```

I need to make sure the file extensions are one of the following: doc, docx, pdf, txt and rtf and that the file size is no larger than 2MB

I am not finding a clear way in the docs to accomplish this. I saw one place that said use this:

```
$form['resume_file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Resume Upload'),
  '#upload_validators'  => array("file_validate_extensions" => array("doc docx pdf txt rtf")),
);
```

but that didn't do anything as far as blocking the wrong filetype and giving an error message. Do I need to do something else like have something extra in my hook_form_validate() function?

I also saw this:

```
$form['resume_file'] = array(
  '#type' => 'file',
  '#title' => t('Resume Upload'),
);

$form['resume_file']['#upload_validators']['file_validate_extensions'][0] = 'doc docx pdf txt rtf';
```

Which also did not do anything. How do I validate for file size and extensions?

Answer (score 4):

It should work actually. We just need to mention `file_validate_extensions` & `file_validate_size` under `upload_validators`.

Example:

```
'#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024*1024),
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you. Where is MAX_FILE_SIZE coming from? I am getting this error: "Use of undefined constant MAX_FILE_SIZE - assumed 'MAX_FILE_SIZE'"  What do I need to put there in the size array to specify 2MB? I don't get the math there.

Comment: Also even if I take MAX_FILE_SIZE out of the equation and just use "'file_validate_size' => array(1000)," as a test, it is still allowing me to upload the wrong filetype and wrong filesize. I do not get an error message. I am using what you you gave me there with 'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),and I tried to upload a .txt file and it went through no problem.

Comment: MAX_FILE_SIZE it the size of you want, ex: for 10mb: `array(10*1024*1024)`

Answer (score 3):

The file upload control in form api in druapl 7 with extension and size validation

```
'resume'=>array(
  '#type'   => "managed_file",
  '#title'  => t("Upload Resume in Word Format"),
  '#descripion' => t("Only doc or docx format Files are allowed."),
  '#upload_location'    => "public://resume/",
  "#upload_validators"  => array("file_validate_extensions" => array("doc docx")),
  '#required'=>TRUE,

),
```

Answer (score 1):

The `#upload_validators` is part of the non-standard form element properties for a managed file form element.

```
$element = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Resume Upload'),
  '#upload_validators' => array(
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
    'file_validate_size' => array(MAX_FILE_SIZE*1024*1024),
  ),
);
```

For more information on the managed file element type see the [Drupal Form API reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file)